# Leaflet: add click event to clustered icons

Tags: onclick, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I would like to add a click event to (subsequently) clustered icons on a leaflet map (using the Leaflet.markercluster plugin). The event itself works, but the alert always yields the very last element of the array for every icon that is clicked. I don't see the reason. declaring 'marker' as array did not change the result.

```
    map.clearLayers;

    var marker = [];

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        disableClusteringAtZoom: 10,
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: true,
        chunkedLoading: true
    });

    for (id in reclist) {       
        var posn = reclist[id]['info'][1];
        var pose = reclist[id]['info'][2];
        var title = reclist[id]['info'][0];
        var mapicon = L.icon({iconUrl: 'url of icon');  

        marker[id] = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(posn, pose), {icon: mapicon})
        .on('click', function(){alert(title)});

        markers.addLayer(marker[id]);

    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are special events for that: see [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#events)

```
markers.on('clusterclick', function() {});
```

Note that it is one event for your cluster. So it is NOT defined in your loop.

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({ ... });
markers.on('clusterclick', function() { ... });
for (id in reclist) { ... }
```

In case I misunderstood your question and you want to define a click event for each markers: if you want to display title, you cannot use the variable as you do. Should do like this:

```
var title = reclist[id]['info'][0];   
var marker = new L.marker(new L.LatLng(posn, pose), {icon: mapicon});
marker.title = title;
marker.on('click', function(e){alert(e.target.title)});
```

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/AuakADHXboI18S81ADjG?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I had initially followed the example in the documentation.The problem is, that each marker is supposed to send its individual id (var title) to the script. That is why I added the event to the marker in the loop and not to the cluster. Actually it amounts to the same thing: both versions only send the very last element of the array. Which is understandable if the event is added to the cluster, but not if the event is added to the marker....

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the exactly what I needed.